# Sessions in php, how to handle log ins

Tags: php, session

I am getting confused about how the `$_SESSION` variable should be used. So far I learned it is used to store temporary data for example if a user logs in I can set some session variables to be able to tell that he/she is logged in. Now my problem is: should I create a session for each user and when the user logs out destroy it or use just one session for all the users?
I am having this doubt because I found this "guide lines" http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL and to log out the users they do:

```
include_once 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();

// Unset all session values 
$_SESSION = array();

// get session parameters 
$params = session_get_cookie_params();

// Delete the actual cookie. 
setcookie(session_name(),
    '', time() - 42000, 
    $params["path"], 
    $params["domain"], 
    $params["secure"], 
    $params["httponly"]);

// Destroy session 
session_destroy();
header('Location: ../index.php');
```

But isn't this code deleting all the values stored in the `$_SESSION` variable therefore all the others users logins?

Comment: I think that you need a better understanding of PHP. This should be asked on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every user (user in terms of browser) on your website gets his own session and therefore sort of his own $_SESSION variable.
You can check your cookies on your website there is usualy one called PHPSESSID with an unique identifier for each user/browser. The session data is stored on the server and only if you have the right session id you get the values in the $_SESSION var.
Now if you destroy this variable for one user **only** his data is gone, the data of all other users is still there and accessible for them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to use a call to `session_regenrate_id(true);` when a user logs in or logs out (or any time their auth* level changes really). This restarts the session with a new ID and copies over all the contents. This can help prevent session fixation if an attacker happens to pull their cookies through an XSS in another, non-logged in part of the site.

Additionally, it's best if you can use the "HTTP only" cookies and HTTPS (secure) too if you run a HTTPS site.